# Localization of CFBundleDisplayName doesn't work on device

Tags: localization, cocos2d-iphone, nslocalizedstring

I tried to make the localization of the app name using CFBundleDisplayName.

I made the localized InfoPlist.strings according two different language.
In one strings file wrote:
    CFBundleDisplayName="x11111"
and in another:
    CFBundleDisplayName="y22222"

And in file info.plist, I added "Application requires iPhone environment" property, and set the boolean value to YES.
And in info.plist,the "Bundle display name" I used "x11111".

The localization worked ok on the simulator, but when tested on the device , it did not work.
On device, the name I used for 'Bundle display name' in info.plist can only be showed.

By the way, I use cocos2d for the project.

Anything I missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your localisation files were supplied to you, and you need to add them, be sure to add them correctly on per file basis. In Xcode, while you are adding files, pay attention how you add them. This is how they should look in Xcode Project Navigator.

I have added them by selecting all folders which didn't add them correctly to project.

[image]